# Need help to sloved "Error: A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'InheritedWidget'" flutter

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-exception

I need help to fix this issue.

---Error---

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_gauges-19.4.56/lib/src/linear_gauge/gauge/linear_gauge_scope.dart:40:10: Error: A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'InheritedWidget'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'InheritedWidget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
        .widget;
         ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I dont know what is it. I am not a flutter developer. So i am asking the flutter developers to help me to solved this issue

Comment: try flutter clean, pub get

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [this issue](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets/issues/731#issuecomment-1128929258) with `syncfusion_flutter_gauges` package that was fixed in version 20.1.56

Try upgrading your dependency to that latest version.